# Empty path name is not legal in MemoryStream in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox, memorystream

What is the solution if there is an error "Empty path name is not legal" because in the database column Filename6 is empty and also what is the solution if between the filename1 to filename6 fields are not found in the image folder?.

Thanks
jack

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SUBFOLDERP").ToString
        Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename1").ToString
        Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename2").ToString
        Dim Filename3 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename3").ToString
        Dim Filename4 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename4").ToString
        Dim Filename5 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename5").ToString
        Dim Filename6 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename6").ToString
        If e.Column.FieldName = "Code" Then
            Dim Code As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
            Dim filePath1 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename1, False)
            Dim filePath2 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename2, False)
            Dim filePath3 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename3, False)
            Dim filePath4 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename4, False)
            Dim filePath5 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename5, False)
            Dim filePath6 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename6, False)
            PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            PictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
            PictureEdit3.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath3)), True, False)
            PictureEdit4.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath4)), True, False)
            PictureEdit5.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath5)), True, False)
            PictureEdit6.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath6)), True, False) 'error this line code
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image: Empty path name is not legal]
[image: view database]

Comment: Test for an empty path before instantiating your memorystream.

Comment: Also check if the file exists in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SUBFOLDERP").ToString
        Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename1").ToString
        Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename2").ToString
        Dim Filename3 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename3").ToString
        Dim Filename4 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename4").ToString
        Dim Filename5 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename5").ToString
        Dim Filename6 As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Filename6").ToString
        If e.Column.FieldName = "Code" Then
            Dim Code As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
            Dim filePath1 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename1, False)
            Dim filePath2 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename2, False)
            Dim filePath3 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename3, False)
            Dim filePath4 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename4, False)
            Dim filePath5 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename5, False)
            Dim filePath6 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename6, False)
            PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            PictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
            PictureEdit3.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath3)), True, False)
            PictureEdit4.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath4)), True, False)
            PictureEdit5.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath5)), True, False)
**If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath6) Then**
            PictureEdit6.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath6)), True, False) 
**End If**
        End If
    End Sub
```